# Origin of "too" ("also")

Tags: etymology, adverbs

Since the South Park joke

> My name is Kyle, too.
>
> Nice to meet you, Kyle-two.

I am wondering and trying to avoid [too](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/too).

Wiktionary explains it as "*deriving from the original meaning of "apart, separately" (compare Old English prefix tō- (“apart”)). More at to.*", which I don't quite understand.

- *tō-* links Proto-Germanic *twiz- "apart, in two", from Proto-Indo-European *dwis- "two-ways, in twain", which is pretty obviously related to *dwo "apart, in two"
- But *to* instead links PIE *de, *do "to"

Is it reflected in *you too have to go*?

The confusing thing about the first variant is that *to* means *for, towards*, quite the opposite of *apart*. Also ... ah, now I see, it could come from a sentence initial adverbial, "apart from that; also; too". German *zwar* comes to mind, that is explained as *zu + wahr* (superficially "too true") and used similar to *zudem* ("add to that"), but rather formulaic.

Comment: Why would you avoid ***too***???